# Crossbrowser print of pdf

Tags: pdf.js

A web application allows a user to print pdf documents using the browser's print dialog. The documents are streamed from a service with mimetype application/pdf. In the web client an iframe is created and appended to the document.body and for the source is set the uri of the service which returns the content.
The frame is as follows:

```
<iframe id="printPage" name="printPage" src="/remote/api/export/resource_name" style="position: absolute; top: -1000px; width: ${opts.frameWidth}px; height: ${opts.frameHeight}px;"></iframe>
```

The print execution part in javascript is like this

```
let iframe = $('the_iframe_html_above');
iframe.load(() => {
  window.frames.printPage.focus();
  window.frames.printPage.print();
});
$('body').append(iframe);
```

In this way the print dialog is opened as expected under Chrome and Safari browser only.

- Under Firefox the dialog is opened but prints about:blank page because the iframe remains empty (there is no content in the body). This happens when pdfjs is disabled from about:config which obviously is OK. If it is not disabled, then FF gives error "Error: Permission denied to access property print" for which there is a 3years old bug reported in mozilla's bugtracker https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911444
- IE and Edge just ignore the onload handler for which I know it is expected but even with an inline onload handler they don't manage to open the print dialog. Only IE gives the file for save/open but not print.

So my question is: If there is a crossbrowser way to perform print operation (open the browser's native print dialog) given these conditions?

Comment: Managed to do that by loading the pdf.js viewer in the iframe, then waiting for the viewer to be ready by handling the _pagesloaded_ event. Then finding the print button in the viewer and clicking it with button.click(). This gave me a complete crossbrowser behavior.